# MATLAB 'fit' function for Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to look for a Python function that is the same as MATLAB's 'fit' function.

Specifically I am looking for something similar to the following MATLAB code:

```
fi = fit(bins, z, cubicinterp)
```

where z and bins are lists.

Answer (score 4):

Try SciPy's [curve_fit()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for general fitting of a function.

For specific interpolations, have a look at SciPy's [interploation functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

Comment: Good answer! However, for what the OP is wanting, you should also mention `numpy.polyfit` and `numpy.polyval`. In her case, the equivalent function is `model = numpy.polyfit(x, y, order=3)` (which can then be evaluated at arbitrary points with `polyval`). http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Comment: Joe, I think I posted my answer within seconds of your comment haha great minds think alike I guess ;) haha

Comment: @Shaun314 :) Still, I was wrong about it being the equivalent function, actually. (It's been awhile since I've used matlab extensively.)  The equivalent function is `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, as Bitwise already pointed out.

Comment: It's been awhile since I used python haha - I gave bitwise an upvote too :)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think there are hundreds of Python functions to do exactly what you want (and much more).

Here is one example using NumPy, but seriously, just google it and you will be amazed:

*[numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)*